# Clockwise Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem understanding this.

Question: Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ that rotates any vector through an angle of $150^\circ$ in the clockwise direction.

The standard matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cosθ &\!\!\!-\sinθ\\
\sinθ &\cosθ\end{pmatrix}$$

Plugging in the value $150$ for the angle does not work and I'm not sure why at this point. Any input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Your matrix rotates a vector in the plane in angle $\,\theta\,$ ...**counterclockwise** ...!

Comment: Would that just mean to reverse both `sin`s ?

Comment: If you meant to ask whether multiplying the sines by $\,-1\,$ will do the job *clockwise* the answer is yes, but more important imo: do you understand, say geometrically, **why** ?

Comment: Yes, I was actually in the midst of checking the geometry as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

The units on the argument for sine and cosine is in radians. You need to convert your 150 degrees to radians if you want to rotate by the proper amount.

$$Radians = \dfrac{\pi}{180}Degrees$$

Furthermore, your matrix is set up to transform in the counterclockwise direction. If you want to rotate in the opposite direction, try plugging in a $-\theta$ and see what that gets you.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. Thank you!